# How to fix the nvidia driver error

Tags: linux

when I trying to install literally anything that requires my graphics card I got this error
[image]

Comment: You could try to move/remove the crash file the error message is telling you about and then try again.

Comment: Please post text instead of pictures of a terminal.  Text has the benefit of being searchable, and accessible to the visually impaired.

Comment: What is your videocard?  Which distro are you using?  Debian does not have `nvidia-340`.  Also note that the `nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver` package is for older videocards (hence my question about which videocard you have).

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug with the nvidia drivers currently being fixed – https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1871268 – title: *Installation fails due to useless immediate configuration error when "Install Third-Party Drivers" is selected*